# Where to buy camping stove canisters by Oslo airport in Norway?

Tags: air-travel, camping, norway

I'm traveling to Norway in a few weeks, arriving to Oslo airport. I'm planning on camping in a tent most of the trip and would like to use my gas stove to make tea/food. Since I can't take the gas canister with me on the flight, I have to buy it when I get to Norway. Can you recommend a sports store near the airport where I could buy one?

Also, I read somewhere (don't remember where anymore) that people often leave their leftover gas canisters in the airport for other (incoming) travelers to use. Is this true? If so, where can I find these leftover canisters?

Comment: I very much doubt that you can leave part-used gas cylinders at an airport. Airports are very much _not_ in the business of storing hazardous substances for random members of the public! You might be remembering a comment on [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/65893/11491), which says that people often leave part-filled canisters at _hostels_.

Comment: purely FTR, I instantly found all of them using google?  (google maps - whatever - just press a button on any electronic device and say "sports store near oslo airport", perhaps "camping store") .. !

Comment: People often leave unwanted equipment at hostels and outfitters. But I've never heard of such a thing at an airport.

Comment: I've seen the leaving of canisters in Reykjavik, but that has a much higher density of hikers. Never seen it in Oslo.

Comment: Exactly what type of stove do you have?

Comment: Where is your first destination? You'll mostly/often be traveling through Oslo city center, in which case it's convenient to just pick something up there.

Answer (score 6):

I haven't been able to find anything about leftover canisters.

However, you could get a new one at the airport. Not at the actual airport, but at a [gas station](https://www.google.no/maps/place/Statoil+Gardermoen/@60.2005367,11.0650401,12z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sbensin!3m4!1s0x0000000000000000:0x2aa1aae92bdeb394!8m2!3d60.188892!4d11.092844) that is directly opposite the airport. I just called them and they sell a gas canister called the [Coleman C500](http://kapitalac.com/kamp/plin-plamenici-grijalice/coleman-c500-propan-butan.html). That's the only one they have. But  it might fit your stove. If it doesn't fit, then read on.

The location nearest to Oslo Airport where I'm sure you can get this is the neighbour town of *Jessheim*. I have found a number of businesses there that almost certainly sell it. I have also phoned the first one on the list, and they have confirmed that they have gas canisters for a variety of stoves.

[G-Sport Jessheim](https://www.google.no/maps/place/G-Sport+Jessheim/@60.1422343,11.1594835,14.47z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1ssport!3m4!1s0x0000000000000000:0xb93125751c304926!8m2!3d60.1431232!4d11.1720389)  **+47 63 97 27 37**

[Sport 1 Superstore Jessheim](https://www.google.no/maps/place/Sport+1+Superstore+Jessheim/@60.1421104,11.1689352,14.47z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1ssport!3m4!1s0x0000000000000000:0x5a1f7b2c6b8ed7be!8m2!3d60.1448163!4d11.1770332) **+47 63 97 20 63**

[Jernia Jessheim Storsenter](https://www.google.no/maps/place/Jernia+Jessheim+Storsenter/@60.1450557,11.1742303,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x46418197412a9d73:0x9b8747fa04f88b84!8m2!3d60.145053!4d11.176419)  **+47 400 05 963**

These businesses are all within walking distance of each other, so if one doesn't have what you're looking for, you can easily walk to the next one. They all open at 10 and close around 8 or 9 on weekdays.

This town is about 10 km from the airport. Will you be renting a car? If so, it's perfectly reasonable to stop by Jessheim and buy everything there. If heading north, though, then it's wiser to stop by Eidsvoll and visit the equivalent shops there.

What is your first destination after the airport? The most convenient thing would be to just buy it there. E.G. if you're taking the express train to Oslo Central Station, then just get the canister at a sports store there. If you're going to Lillehammer, then buy it there, etc. Even small towns usually have a sports or hardware store. You might want to call them first (they will almost always speak decent English) to make sure they have what you need.

So, if you buy it in a town you'll already be passing through on your journey, you may save yourself a possible detour through Jessheim or Eidsvoll.

Although it might exist, I'm not personally aware of any place where you can get second hand canisters. The easiest way may be to buy a new one.

Comment: For the record: If you're camping in the woods/mountains in Norway, chances are you'll pass by DNT cabins. One _might_ find second hand gas canisters at those cabins, or if it's a manned cabin, you might buy new ones. Gambling on this is risky though, since if you're at a DNT cabin, you're probably _far_ from a gas station or sports store. Therefore, you shouldn't plan on getting your gas here, but it might be nice to know where to look if you run out...

Comment: @StewieGriffin I agree with that. But OP may not see your comment, as he/she won't be pinged. Also, OP seems to have abandoned this question.

Comment: Future visitors... Future visitors =)

Comment: @StewieGriffin Sure, sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Gas Canisters can be found in most sports or DIY stores near Oslo Airport. Depending on where you plan to travel from the airport, depends what is most convenient for you, but I would advise you to check out one of the below links. I can't give you a more specific answer, because I don't know the details of your travel plans once arriving in Norway.

- [Link 1](http://www.campingaz.com/Benelux/c-604-cartridges-cylinders.aspx) - a well known retailer called Campingz with stores in Norway that stocks canisters of gas. This link will take you to a page showing you available products. To search for retailers, click [here](http://www.campingaz.com/Benelux/t-retailerlocator.aspx)
- [Link 2](https://www.oslosportslager.no/sok.aspx?q=gas) [(store can be found here)](https://www.google.sk/maps/dir/Oslo+Airport,+Edvard+Munchs+veg,+Gardermoen,+Norway/Oslo+Sportslager+AS,+Torggata,+Oslo,+Norway/@60.0484176,10.6776782,10z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x4641838b248a1cbf:0xcca0add4a7eb5b82!2m2!1d11.1004153!2d60.1975501!1m5!1m1!1s0x46416e63e7986023:0x2c7300409f311a7a!2m2!1d10.751795!2d59.916311)

Canisters can also be found just outside Oslo at railway stations - here are two.

[Lillestrøm railway station:](https://www.google.sk/maps/dir//Lillestr%C3%B8m+stasjon,+Jonas+Lies+gate,+2000+Lillestr%C3%B8m,+Norway/@44.7621748,-85.351954,3z/data=!4m16!1m7!3m6!1s0x46417ca091e9a19b:0x7a301519507c6ac6!2sLillestr%C3%B8m+stasjon!3b1!8m2!3d59.9534447!4d11.0453159!4m7!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x46417ca091e9a19b:0x7a301519507c6ac6!2m2!1d11.0453159!2d59.9534447) Shell Lillestrøm Bilistsenter, Jernbanegata 3, +47 63 81 21 15

[Skøyen railway station:](https://www.google.sk/maps/dir//Sk%C3%B8yen,+0277+Oslo,+Norway/@59.9224317,10.6078282,12z/data=!4m16!1m7!3m6!1s0x46416db3eadc89c9:0xc1ff164d478d9226!2zU2vDuHllbg!3b1!8m2!3d59.9223642!4d10.677868!4m7!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x46416db3eadc89c9:0xc1ff164d478d9226!2m2!1d10.677868!2d59.9223642)Statoil Skøyen, Drammensveien 161, +47 22 51 17 90 (24/7)

Gas stations in Norway [like this one](https://www.google.no/maps/place/Statoil+Gardermoen/@60.2005367,11.0650401,12z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sbensin!3m4!1s0x0000000000000000:0x2aa1aae92bdeb394!8m2!3d60.188892!4d11.092844) will usually be able to sell you canisters of gas. If none of the above suggestions are useful, you could try a passing gas station as they may stock what you need.

It's very unlikely that you would get left over canisters at the airport.

Comment: Your first link directs to a Netherlands-based site, in Dutch, that has nothing to do with Oslo/Norway. Please strive more for quality than just quantity in your contributions to this site! Choose and check your sources carefully and dare to leave a question open if you can not find a good answer to it! Your second link is in downtown Oslo, not the airport, which might still be useful but worth pointing out.

Comment: If you were to research, you would see that link 1 is for a retailer well known in Norway - link 1 is just for informational purposes in which it tells you available products. I can see no problems with any of these sources. @mts If you know any better, please by all means comment them below or add an answer yourself.

Comment: Nathan,  these are valid suggestions. A bit far from the airport,  maybe,  but still potentially useful.  But I don't understand "Link 1", what exactly is it?  Could you clarify? @mts

Comment: Hi @Fiksdal, please see my edit and let me know if this clarifies it.

Comment: @NathanShoesmith Yes, now I understand. Thanks.